# Server Error in '/' Application. ASP.Net MVC Visual Studio 2019

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

Whenever I run the program, it works perfectly. However, as soon as I hit the "Login" button it tells me

**Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.**

**Requested URL: /LoginController/Authorize**

I checked everything and the spelling is correct. I am new to this and cannot figure out what I am doing wrong. Any guidance would be highly appreciated it.

Inside of the `App_Start` folder I have my `RouteConfig.cs` file. It contains the following:

```
namespace CoffeeShop_Web_App
{
    public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "LoginController", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

I have one controller which is my `LoginController.cs` which contains the following.

```
namespace CoffeeShop_Web_App.Controllers
{
    public class LoginController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Login
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Authorize()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

Lastly, my only view `Index.cshtml` which contains the following.

```
@model CoffeeShop_Web_App.Models.OwnerLogin
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Login</title>
    <style>
        #login-div {
            position: absolute;
            left: 40%;
            top: 40%;
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
            padding:  10px 10px;
        }


    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="login-div">
        @using (Html.BeginForm("Authorize", "LoginController", FormMethod.Post))
        {
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td style="text-decoration:underline">Coffee Shop</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.USERNAME)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.USERNAME)
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.USERNAME)</td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PASSWORD)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PASSWORD)
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PASSWORD)</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="submit" name="name" value="Login" />
                        <input type="reset" name="name" value="Clear" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        }
    </div>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your form is posting back to the `Authorize` method of `LoginController` controller:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Authorize", "LoginController", FormMethod.Post))
```

You don't have to specify controller suffix for the name of the controller. The following should fix it:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Authorize", "Login", FormMethod.Post))
```

Also you did the same mistake when setting up the routing too:

```
defaults: new { controller = "LoginController", action = "Index", 
    id = UrlParameter.Optional }
```

which should have been just:

```
defaults: new { controller = "Login", action = "Index", 
    id = UrlParameter.Optional }
```

Comment: Thank you for this! I went ahead and made corrections as so, however now it tells me Server Error in '/' Application. The view 'Authorize' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. Then it lists the locations that was searched. I am a bit confused, can I not have another method within the same view?

Comment: @beloas: by default, the view will be generated using the same name as your method, and under a folder named the same as your controller, minus the suffix under Views folder. If your controller was previously named as LoginController Controller, and you used the scaffold way to create the Authorize view, it might probably be under the wrong folder.

Comment: By the way, this is not how you do authentication though just in case. You should take a look at: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: Thank you for the clarification! Greatly appreciated!